# How to quiet Maven "props" log output?

Tags: maven

When using [-q option](http://jan.baresovi.cz/dr/en/maven-command-line) with Maven it quiets all log output, except "props". I would like to quiet those "props" outputs, how to do that ??

I'm running:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.0.2 -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

Output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Products
[INFO] Products :: Base
[INFO] Products :: Badges
[INFO] Assembly
Downloading: http://nexus.xxx
Downloading: http://nexus.xxx
Downloaded: http://nexus.xxx (17 KB at 85.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://nexus.xxx (27 KB at 136.0 KB/sec)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Project 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.0:set (default-cli) @ campaigns ---
[INFO] Processing
[INFO]     Updating project
[INFO]         from version 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT to 0.0.2
Props: {project.version=0.0.2, project.artifactId=campaigns, project.groupId=campaigns}
Props: {project.version=0.0.2, project.artifactId=campaigns, project.groupId=campaigns}
Props: {project.version=0.0.2, project.artifactId=campaigns, project.groupId=campaigns}
Props: {project.version=0.0.2, project.artifactId=campaigns, project.groupId=campaigns}
Props: {project.version=0.0.2, project.artifactId=campaigns, project.groupId=campaigns}
```

If I use the -q option it quiets all "info" and "download", but not the "props".

I have a project which produces 60 MB of "props" in the build log for each "mvn versions:set" command, so I'd really like to know how to quiet those "props".

Maybe it is a bug in [Maven versions plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) that it doesn't quiet those "props" even when -q option is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress the output of

```
Downloading: http://nexus.xxx
Downloading: http://nexus.xxx
Downloaded: http://nexus.xxx (17 KB at 85.4 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://nexus.xxx (27 KB at 136.0 KB/sec)
```

via the Maven batch option just simply use:

```
mvn --batch-mode ...
```

The output of the Props is in the responsibility of the appropriate maven plugin in your case the [versions-mave-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).

Comment: The "download" output is being suppressed already by using the -q option.
The question is then how to suppress the "props" from the versions plugin?

Comment: Ah sorry. Misunderstand the question. You can only check if the plugin has an appropriate configuration otherwise not possible.

Comment: Haven't been able to find any configuration related to "props" in the versions plugin documentation, hence this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is very annoying indeed, but apparently there is a [bug](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MVERSIONS-223) reported with a patch. So this might be patched somewhen.